# WHILE loop to update records from mapping table

Tags: sql-server

I have a mapping table:

```
MappingTable
OLD_ID    NEW_ID
1234      A-98276
1345      A-78473
7635      A-89328
```

**There are about 10,000 rows in the mapping table.**

I have another table that has the OLD_IDs and I need to update the values in the OLD_ID with the value NEW_ID.

```
TestTable
OLD_ID
1234
7635
1345
```

The query would be:

```
UPDATE TestTable SET OLD_ID = 'A-98276' WHERE OLD_ID = '1234'
```

I need to do this for each row in TestTable. I know this is possible with the WHILE LOOP but am not sure how to do it. There has to be a way to get the row number...

```
DECLARE @count, @i INT
SET @count = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TestTable
SET @i = 1
WHILE (@i < @count)
BEGIN
   UPDATE TestTable SET OLD_ID = (SELECT NEW_ID FROM MappingTable WHERE OLD_ID = @???)
   SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A loop shouldn't be necessary.  It seems you're looking for something like this

```
update t
set OLD_ID=m.NEW_ID
from TestTable t
     join MappingTable m on t.OLD_ID=m.OLD_ID;
```

Comment: Thanks.  That should do it. I'll give this a try!